# X axis labels do not appear when using subplots

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

My x labels are not showing in the subplots even though I have explicitly instructed matplotlib to draw them.

At first, I suspected that the other plots were having their labels obscured by the subplot below, so I used plt.tight_layout() to add extra space between the subplots, yet I still do not see my x labels, only more whitespace. I suspect that the whitespace is covering up my labels, but I am not certain.

If I transpose the array of subplots, the labels do appear, but this violates the requirements that I am working under.

```py
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

FOR = '15'
SAT = "J02"
ranges = np.array([[-1000, 1000], [-1000, 1000]])
Final= pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(ranges[:, 0], ranges[:, 1], size=(30, ranges.shape[0])), columns=('In_Track','Cross_Track'))
LifeTime = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(ranges[:, 0], ranges[:, 1], size=(4000, ranges.shape[0])), columns=('In_Track','Cross_Track'))
Hundred = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(ranges[:, 0], ranges[:, 1], size=(300, ranges.shape[0])), columns=('In_Track','Cross_Track'))
Final.insert(0, 'd', [dt.datetime(2001,9,11)]*len(Final))
LifeTime.insert(0, 'd', [dt.datetime(2001,9,11)]*len(LifeTime))
Hundred.insert(0, 'd', [dt.datetime(2001,9,11)]*len(Hundred))

ThreePanel, (ax1a, ax2a, ax3a) = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, sharex=False, sharey=True, figsize=(10.8, 19.2), dpi=100)
datestring="02-29-2016"
ax1a.plot(range(1, 31), Final['In_Track'], 'b-*', label='inTrack')
ax1a.plot(range(1, 31), Final['Cross_Track'], 'r-*', label=' xTrack')
yrange = [-3000,3000]
ax1a.set_ylim(yrange)
ax1a.grid(True)
ax1a.set_ylabel('Angle   ['+r'$\mu$'+ 'rad]')
ax1a.set_xlabel('FOR Scan Position')
ax1a.set_title('Geolocation Accuracy relative to VIIRS\nfor' + ' ' + SAT + ' on ' + datestring)
ax1a.legend(loc='best')
ax1b = ax1a.twinx()   # mirror them
ax1b.set_ylim(np.array(yrange)/16808. * 100.)
ax1b.set_ylabel('Percentage of FOV Size [%]')#\nfootprint semiaxes ranges from 14x14km at FOR 15 to 48x24km at FORs 1 & 30')
ax1b.set_xlabel('FOR Scan Position')

LifeTime.plot(kind='line', y='In_Track', ax=ax2a)
LifeTime.plot(kind='line', y='Cross_Track', ax=ax2a)
ax2a.set_xlabel('Date')
yrange = [-3000, 3000]
ax2a.set_ylim(yrange)
ax2a.set_ylabel('Angle   ['+r'$\mu$'+ 'rad]')
ax2a.grid(True)
ax2b = ax2a.twinx() #mirror yaxis
ax2b.set_ylim(np.array(yrange)/16808. * 100.)
ax2b.set_ylabel('Percentage of FOV Size [%]')
ax2b.axhline(y=10.7, c ='m', ls='--')
ax2b.axhline(y=-10.7, c ='m', ls='--')
DateDiff = '300 Days'
ax2a.set_title(DateDiff + ' of Geolocation Accuracy relative to VIIRS for FOR Scan Position: ' + FOR)

#ax3a = plt.subplot(3,1,3, sharex=None)
Hundred.plot(kind='line', y='In_Track', ax=ax3a)
Hundred.plot(kind='line', y='Cross_Track', ax=ax3a)
ax3a.set_xlabel('Date')
yrange = [-3000, 3000]
ax3a.set_ylim(yrange)
ax3a.set_ylabel('Angle   ['+r'$\mu$'+ 'rad]')
ax3a.grid(True)
ax3b = ax3a.twinx() #mirror yaxis
ax3b.set_ylim(np.array(yrange)/16808. * 100.)
ax3b.set_ylabel('Percentage of FOV Size [%]')
DateDiff = '100 Days'
ax3a.set_title(DateDiff + ' of Geolocation Accuracy relative to VIIRS for FOR Scan Position: ' + FOR)
ThreePanel.tight_layout(pad=0.4, w_pad=0.5, h_pad=10)

outfilename = 'Reproducible.png'
plt.savefig(outfilename)
```

In my reproducible code above, I set explicit x labels for each of 3 different subplots. However, only the bottom-most subplot displays its x labels.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask me the specifics but calling the plot method of dataframes does all kinds of unknown formatting behind the scenes.  If you plot the data from the axis.plot method instead, everything shows up, though you will have to change your layout settings:

```py
# LifeTime.plot(kind='line', y='In_Track', ax=ax2a)
# LifeTime.plot(kind='line', y='Cross_Track', ax=ax2a)
ax2a.plot(LifeTime.index, LifeTime.In_Track)
ax2a.plot(LifeTime.index, LifeTime.Cross_Track)

# Hundred.plot(kind='line', y='In_Track', ax=ax3a)
# Hundred.plot(kind='line', y='Cross_Track', ax=ax3a)
ax3a.plot(Hundred.index, Hundred.In_Track)
ax3a.plot(Hundred.index, Hundred.Cross_Track)
```